# React-Native-Camera - Cannot read property 'Aspect' of Undefined

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

So I'm getting a cannot read property 'Aspect' of undefined error when trying to run the React Native Camera https://github.com/lwansbrough/react-native-camera

[image]

I'm aware of this GitHub issue https://github.com/lwansbrough/react-native-camera/issues/386

However, I've tried basically everything in there and still getting the error. Do I actually have to downgrade from IOS10 on the Simulator to use it? Would really prefer not to have to do that. Has anyone come up with any type of workaround?

I'm running Version 8.1 (8B62)

I tried installing manually, resetting cache, adding code to RCTCameraManager.m etc. Nothing.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried rebuilding the application on your device/simulator? Like deleting the app and re-installing with 'react-native run-ios'

Comment: Deleting the app? I tried quitting simulator and terminal and running react native run iOS again.

Comment: check manual install step 5 https://github.com/lwansbrough/react-native-camera

Comment: @BurakKarasoy I did that and everything looked fine. Paths are the same as in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

I also have this issue. Then I find that I missed two steps in the documentation.

First remember to add permissions in plist file.

```
<key>NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription</key>
<string>Your message to user when the camera is accessed for the first time</string>
<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
<string>Your message to user when the camera is accessed for the first time</string>
<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
<string>Your message to user when the photo library is accessed for the first time</string>
<key>NSMicrophoneUsageDescription</key>
```

Then remember to add dependency in your podfile.

```
pod 'react-native-camera', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-camera'
```

and run `pod install`.

For me it works after these two steps. If it still not work, check if you link the library properly.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I missed adding `libRNCamera.a` to my project's `Build Phases` ➜ `Link Binary With Libraries`